# Disable hover text in plotly with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to partly disable hover text in plotly, limiting it to one dataframe or geom in ggplot. In the case below, I want hover only on the "cities" not the map outline. I've seen a solution in Python, but not R. And how would I control the image size to keep the map dimension right in plotly? The map demo at https://plot.ly/ggplot2/interactive-tooltip/ seems not to care!

```
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


Japan <- map_data("world2Hires", region="Japan")

Longitude <- 140
Latitude <- 36.5
df <- cbind.data.frame(Longitude,Latitude)
df$Name <- "Tokyo"
df$Name_2 <- "Tōkyō"



XX <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=Japan, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="black", fill="white", text="") + coord_equal() + geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, text=Name), color="green")
XX 
ggplotly(XX)  ##How to get hover text only on df not Japan, and remove "[object Object]" 

XX <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=Japan, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="black", fill="white", text="") + coord_equal() + geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, text=Name_2), color="green")
XX 
ggplotly(XX)  ##Non-Ascii text breaks hover
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I have to admit I don't know about plotly and mapdata packages before reading your question. But these look so useful I started playing around and finally produced something useful.

I think some of your problems arising because you use the `ggplotly` function and not the direct `plot_ly` interface, which I did in my solution.

**data preparation**

```
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

Japan <- map_data("world2Hires", region="Japan")
Longitude <- 140
Latitude <- 36.5
df <- cbind.data.frame(Longitude,Latitude)
df$Name <- "Tokyo"
df$Name_2 <- "Tōkyō"
```

**geo object**

Here a dummy geo object is prepared. This doesn't draw anything but selects which region of the World to display. Here you could also set up the used projection.

```
g <- list(
  showland = F,
  coastlinewidth = 0,
  lonaxis = list(
    showgrid = TRUE,
    gridwidth = 0.5,
    range = c(125, 145.8224),
    dtick = 5
  ),
  lataxis = list(
    showgrid = TRUE,
    gridwidth = 0.5,
    range = c(25, 45.52),
    dtick = 5
  )
)
```

**adding data**

First create a `scattergeo` plot with only your point:

```
p <- plot_ly(data = df,lon = Longitude,lat = Latitude,name="City",
             text =Name_2,type = "scattergeo",mode = "markers")
```

Then add the cost line and disable hover info (`hoverinfo = "none"`):

```
p <- add_trace(data=Japan,lon = long,lat = lat, 
               mode = "lines",group=group,line = list(color=toRGB("black"),width = 0.5),
               type = "scattergeo",  hoverinfo = "none",showlegend = F)
```

Finally set the layout to the previously defined geo object:

```
p <- layout(p, geo = g)
```

**Final remarks**

https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-geo shows what parameters are available for a geo object. https://plot.ly/r/lines-on-maps/ shows a code example with some of them.

For me using `Name_2` works fine and I don't know what you mean with "control the image size" you might want to ask different questions for that where you further specify what you want. Good luck!

Comment: This works perfectly, although it confirms my sense that plotly is more reliable than ggplotly. Your answer also helped with my question about how to control the image size. It's the height and width parameters within layout()

Comment: Glad I could help. Did the display issue worked out ?

Comment: Yes, it works locally and on the remote server. Thanks. Next is integration with Shiny!

Comment: Checkout https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-geo for "what exact parameters are available for a geo object" @bluefish

Comment: Thanks I added it to the answer @user1561393

Comment: @bluefish: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242473/r-adding-a-tool-tip-to-interactive-plot-plotly thanks!