# Remove column name from hover text

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

How can I remove the `cyl:` in the hovertext of the plot below?

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = cyl)) + geom_point(),
         tooltip = c("colour"))
```

[image]

Comment: How tried looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108350/disable-hover-text-in-plotly-with-ggplot?rq=1). Maybe it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way to do it, but you could try:

```
b <- ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = cyl)) + geom_point(),
          tooltip = c("colour"))
p <- plotly_build(b) 
p$data[[1]]$text
library(stringr)
p$data[[1]]$text <- str_sub(p$data[[1]]$text,-2,-1)
p
```

You just need to replace the text showed when you hover by something else you want. In your example, I simply extracted that last digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text` aesthetic to display the value without the column name:

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(ggplot(
  mtcars, 
  aes(mpg, hp, colour = cyl, text = cyl)) + geom_point(),
  tooltip = c("text")
))
```

You can also use `text` to paste in strings or styling, without this code appearing as a "column name":

```
ggplotly(ggplot(
  mtcars, 
  aes(mpg, hp, colour = cyl, text = paste("Cylinders: ", cyl)) + 
    geom_point(),
  tooltip = c("text")
))
```

It's not terribly well documented, but see [here](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2016/11/07/interactive-r-plots-with-ggplot2-and-plotly/) for more information.