# R: Adding a "tool tip" to interactive plot (plotly)

Tags: r, dplyr, hover, plotly, tooltip

I am using the R programming language. From a previous post ([R: Plot not Fully Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821992/r-plot-not-fully-loading)), I learned how to make interactive plots in R using plotly :

```
library(plotly)

iris %>% plot_ly(type = 'parcoords', line = list(color = ~as.integer(Species), 
         colorscale = list(c(0,'red'),c(0.5,'green'),c(1,'blue'))), 
         dimensions = list( list(range = c(2,4.5), label = 'Sepal Width', values = ~Sepal.Width), 
                      list(range = c(4,8), constraintrange = c(5,6), label = 'Sepal Length', values = ~Sepal.Length), 
                      list(range = c(0,2.5), label = 'Petal Width', values = ~Petal.Width), 
                      list(range = c(1,7), label = 'Petal Length', values = ~Petal.Length) ) )
```

[image]

Suppose if I was to add an "id" column to the data set, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- iris %>% mutate(id = row_number())
```

Is it possible so that when you "click" on any of the "lines" on this plot, information from the dataset (i.e. "df") corresponding to row of that line appears?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This [github issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3012) looks like it may be related to this.

Comment: @Ben: do you have any idea how to adapt this code so that it works for the problem I am working on?

Comment: You can refer to this https://plotly.com/ggplot2/interactive-tooltip/ maybe it can help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Did not run your code, but you may need to prepare all the text as one string in the column beforehand and use text = ~tooltip_column to display it.
It may work with \n for line splits

```
  fig <- plot_ly(
    type = 'scatter3D',
    x = -calcDataMeas2$pos_X,
    y = calcDataMeas2$pos_Y,
    z = z_value,
    text = calcDataMeas2$tube_name,
    scene = 'scene1',
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = marker
  )
```